# Same node, different templates in Drupal, how to do?

Tags: drupal, templates

I have a content type which displays an image.

When this image is displayed as regular node page (node/xxx), I would like it to use the regular template file.

When this image is displayed in a modal (Lightbox2 popup modal), I would like it to use another template file (to remove the header and footer, change background, etc).

How can I set two different templates for the same node?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `page-node-lightbox2.tpl.php` which can be found in the lightbox2 module folder.  Copy that file to your theme folder and make all the changes you want, then clear your cache (www.example.com/admin/settings/performance) and you should see the changes to the modal view of your images.